# Create a Timeline View using BezierPath in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

i am trying to draw a milestone in TableView with 5 rows, i have added a label in cell as "O",here row height is 44 and am trying to connect these dots
Something like this 
O------O------O------O-----O vertically, but i am unable to figure out what am missing here, refer the following code

```
 class StopslistTableViewCell:UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var milestoneLbl: UILabel!

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let scrrenX = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30

    let frametosuperview = milestoneLbl.convert(milestoneLbl!.frame, to: self.superview)

    print("dotframetosuperview",frametosuperview)

    //print(CGPoint(x: scrrenX, y: previousposY + rect.size.height))

    //frametosuperview.origin.y > 40 ? frametosuperview.origin.y - 20 : frametosuperview.origin.y

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: scrrenX, y:frametosuperview.origin.y < 30 ? frametosuperview.origin.y : frametosuperview.origin.y - frametosuperview.height))

    print("move to point--->",frametosuperview.origin.y < 30 ? frametosuperview.origin.y : frametosuperview.origin.y - frametosuperview.height)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: scrrenX, y: frametosuperview.origin.y < 30 ? frametosuperview.height + 24 : (frametosuperview.origin.y + 24)))
    print("add line to point--->",CGPoint(x: scrrenX, y: frametosuperview.origin.y < 30 ? frametosuperview.height + 24 : (frametosuperview.origin.y + 24)))

    path.lineWidth = 5

    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    path.stroke()

    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

debug output

```
dotframetosuperview (560.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0) 
move to point---> 20.0
add line to point---> (290.0, 44.0)
dotframetosuperview (560.0, 64.0, 20.0, 20.0)
move to point---> 44.0
add line to point---> (290.0, 88.0)
dotframetosuperview (560.0, 108.0, 20.0, 20.0)
move to point---> 88.0
add line to point---> (290.0, 132.0)
dotframetosuperview (560.0, 152.0, 20.0, 20.0)
move to point---> 132.0
add line to point---> (290.0, 176.0)
dotframetosuperview (560.0, 196.0, 20.0, 20.0)
move to point---> 176.0
add line to point---> (290.0, 220.0)
```

i need something like this

[image]

I am unable to get the desired results,am i missing something here..?

Comment: Please post more info. What is the issue "I am unable to get the desired results"? Expected output, actual output ...

Comment: if you want more info,copy the code in tableviewcell, get a tableview in xib,drag a cell,put a label on it,attach the label to milestone and run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont need to create a `UILabel`.Instead create a circle and a Line with Dashed pattern as :

```
let offSet:CGFloat = 20.0
let circleRadius:CGFloat = 5.0

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    //creating a circle
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: offSet,y: circleRadius), radius: CGFloat(circleRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
    circlePath.stroke()

    //creating a line with dashed pattern
    let  dashPath = UIBezierPath()
    let  startPoint = CGPoint(x:offSet  ,y:circleRadius * 2)
    dashPath.move(to: startPoint)

    let  endPoint = CGPoint(x:offSet,y:
        self.bounds.maxY)
    dashPath.addLine(to: endPoint)

    let  dashes: [ CGFloat ] = [4, 1] //line with dash pattern of 4 thick and i unit space
    dashPath.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)
    dashPath.lineWidth = 2.0
    dashPath.lineCapStyle = .butt
    UIColor.black.set()
    dashPath.stroke()

}
```

Output:
[image]

**EDIT:** Since OP wants the timeline circle to appear from the center of the cell.

```
var allRows = Int()
var currentIndexPath = IndexPath()
let offSet:CGFloat = 20.0
let circleRadius:CGFloat = 5.0


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    //creating a circle
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: offSet,y: self.bounds.midY), radius: CGFloat(circleRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
    circlePath.stroke()

    //creating a line with dashed pattern
    let  dashPath = UIBezierPath()
    var startPoint = CGPoint()

    if currentIndexPath.row  == 0{

        startPoint = CGPoint(x:offSet  ,y:self.bounds.midY)
    }else{

        startPoint = CGPoint(x:offSet  ,y:0)
    }
    dashPath.move(to: startPoint)

    var endPoint = CGPoint()

    if currentIndexPath.row == allRows-1{

        endPoint = CGPoint(x:offSet,y:
            self.bounds.midY)
    }else{

        endPoint = CGPoint(x:offSet,y:
            self.bounds.maxY)

    }
    dashPath.addLine(to: endPoint)

    let  dashes: [ CGFloat ] = [4, 1] //line with dash pattern of 4 thick and i unit space
    dashPath.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)
    dashPath.lineWidth = 2.0
    dashPath.lineCapStyle = .butt
    UIColor.black.set()
    dashPath.stroke()
}
```

And your  `cellForRowAt indexPath` should be configure as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        .......
        cell.allRows = totalNumberOfRows
        cell.currentIndexPath = indexPath
        return cell


    }
```

This results in following O/P:
[image]

Comment: well it did answer the question, but what my intention for that question was, "Why this code is not drawing as i intended as the x,y cords seems to be correct", also i used label so that i didn't have to reset the frame of circle everytime i move the position of the milestone

Comment: @iSwift The solution you were building was just a hack putting a rounded UILabel and a dotted line..So ,i thought i would post a better answer to do in a correct way.

Comment: let say i wan to put the circle in middle, but the line start point should be from first circle center to the end circles center

Comment: @iSwift Please clarify clearly..May be a screenshot..It would be better to post a new question.

Comment: Please try on your own if not i will edit when i am free.

Comment: no problem whenever u have time i have also attached a image for refence, and i indeed tried my best to solve it with multiple options, that i why am asking at stack

Comment: thanks.. also i would like to know why the code i have posted doesn't provide the same result as the y cords seems correct to draw a path.

Comment: @iSwift Replace your x value to hardcoded o and debug y value..You will know it

Comment: Y dots going inside circle in second image..Can you fix this?